# Weierstrass Points on Quartics

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a smooth projective plane quartic. We say that $P \in V$ is a Weierstrass point if $\dim(L(gP)) \geq 2$. We say that a point $Q$ is a point of inflexion if the tangent line at $Q$ intersects $Q$ with multiplicity at least 3.

How do I show that, for the special case of $V$ a plane quartic, these definitions coincide, in the sense that being an inflexion point is equivalent to being a Weierstrass point?

Please don't give an answer involving things like schemes and sheaves - let's keep it in the language of varieties. I know the statement of the Riemann-Roch theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Weierstrass point of a smooth projective curve $C$ (compact Riemann surface, if you prefer) is a ramification point of the complete canonical series $K_C$. In other words, it is a point $P\in C$ such that $h^0(K_C(-gP))>0$, where $g=g_C$. This is equivalent to $h^0(gP)>1$, as you mention (by Riemann-Roch $+$ Serre duality).

> In other words, $P\in C$ is a Weierstrass point iff the canonical series
>   $K_C$ has a (nonzero) section vanishing at least $g_C$ times at $P$.

If $C$ is a smooth plane quartic, any canonical divisor consists of four aligned points on the curve. In other words, the canonical series is the linear series cut out by lines, $$K_C=\mathscr O_C(1).$$
Since $g=3$, a point $P\in C$ is Weierstrass iff $\mathscr O_C(1)$ has a (nonzero) section
vanishing at least $3$ times at $P$. But this is the definition of an inflexion point.

---

*Aside*. It is true for every smooth plane curve $C$ of degree $d$ that $K_C=\mathscr O_C(d-3)$.

Comment: I know that the canonical divisor of a curve is the divisor associated with any Kahler differential. Is this the same as what you call the 'complete canonical series'? Also, is your second paragraph the genus 2 analogue of the fact that genus 1 curves have a group structure which is given by 'sets of 3 point on a line?' Thanks

Comment: Yes, and "complete" only refers to considering the full vector space of sections (i.e. Kahler differentials). No, a group structure on a curve is very special to genus $1$. That paragraph just says that a canonical divisor is the intersection of the curve with a line in $\mathbb P^2$.

Comment: I'm fine with your argument. However, you seem to assume the statement 'If $V$ is a plane quartic and $K_V$ is canonical with $K$ equivalent to $A+B+C+D$ then $A,B,C,D$ lie on some projective line.' How does one justify this?

Comment: The only statement I assume is $K_C=\mathscr O_C(1)$, which is indeed equivalent to what you are asking. This follows from adjunction formula, and $K_{\mathbb P^2}=\mathscr O(-3)$.